# Garbled graphics on Windows10

Tags: windows-10, graphics

I'm noticing a strange graphics issue that only shows up in certain graphics display on Windows.

Most graphics display on the windows is fine and I've run bios graphics and memory tests and there doesn't seem to be an issue.

I also experience graphics issues when I use Visio.

Any ideas on what it could be and if there is a fix for it?

[garbled windows status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXKJR.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Update your Video driver, Chipset if Laptop, and BIOS